# Definite integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$ $ 
I'm wondering how to approach the following definite integral:

$$\int_{-400}^{400} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \int_{-400}^{400} \DeclareMathOperator{\sinc}{sinc} \sinc(x) dx$$

I tried taylor expanding and integrating the polynomial but then I get a divergent series.

Comment: You may want to check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral. The result is $2Si(400)$

Comment: You wouldn't get a divergent series but you would get a series that converges very very slowly when its argument is as big as $400,$ so it will look as if it diverges if you look at only the first several hundred terms.

Comment: When I see people voting to close a question like this as "off topic" I wonder what's wrong with them.

Comment: It is actually something called a "sin integral."  It cannot be expressed as elementary functions.  However as the limits approach $(-\infty, \infty)$ it actually becomes easier to integrate, and the integral approaches $ \pi$

Comment: There's a $ \pi $ of the real line for you not appearing to be about math

Comment: We know you are not a real person Mr. Community.

Answer (score 3):

For large $a$, you can do asymptotics and find
$$
\int_{-a}^a \frac{\sin x}{x}dx \sim \pi - \left( \frac2{a} - \frac4{a^3}\right)\cos a  - \left( \frac2{a^2} - \frac{12}{a^4}\right)\sin a  
$$
For $a$ as large as 400, this will be accurate to better than a part in a million.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{\sin(x)}x\,dx = \pi - 2\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}x\,dx$$
Integrating by parts the RHS integral:
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}x\,dx = \frac{\cos a}a - \int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx
$$
and you have the trivial bounding
$$
\left|\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}\,dx\right|\le\frac1a.
$$
Repeating the procedure you can get better bounds.